# Usage of "except", "but" and "other than"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Should nouns before **'except'**, '**other than'** and **'but'** be plural or singular? I have given some example sentences.

> 1- I don't have any ***friend(s) but/except/other than*** you.
>
> 2- I have no ***friend(s) but/except/other than*** you.
>
> 3- I don't have a friend **except/but** you.

I think plural nouns are more common in this case. Could any native speakers please answer this question for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [this NGram...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=had%20no%20friend%20but%2Chad%20no%20friends%20but%2Chad%20no%20friend%20except%2Chad%20no%20friends%20except&year_start=1860&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chad%20no%20friend%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20no%20friends%20but%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20no%20friend%20except%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20no%20friends%20except%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...which I think confirms my main thoughts on this matter. Firstly, *both singular and plural are valid*. But I think it's also clear than ***but*** in such contexts is a declining usage, and that the trend is increasingly towards using a plural after ***no***.

I don't see much point in trying to identify a *semantic* distinction between singular and plural, since inherently the context must always imply at least the *possibility* that there might have been multiple *friends* or whatever (otherwise why bother to deny that they exist?).